# OpenOffice Bootstrap stuck when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, openoffice.org

I have C# code to convert documents to PDF using OpenOffice. It works fine when I ran project from visual studio but when I deployed it on IIS, it got stuck. I can see new OpenOffice processes in task manager whenever `uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap()` is called but nothing happens afterward.

I have tried enabling 32 bit Application Support on IIS.
Changing Application pool to NetworkService, LocalSystem, my wwn logged in user and after that restarting IIS. Nothing seems to work.
There is no error displayed related to error while loading `*_cli` assemblies.

OpenOffice version is 4 with .Net version 4.5.

Comment: Maybe you are some missing assembly on your project....do you have some logging package installed(f.i: log4net or nlog) on your project?

Comment: I don't have logging package installed. It didn't give any kind of error. Request just keep on loading forever.

Comment: i have the same problem... any help?